# How can one securely hash passwords server side while avoiding DoS?

Tags: passwords, hash, denial-of-service

It is generally recommended that one use a slow hash function to hash passwords. However, does this create a DoS risk?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12101/prevent-denial-of-service-attacks-against-slow-hashing-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could, in addition to using a slow hash function, limit the number of requests per second a particular user could send. For instance, if you're getting 30 failed login requests from a particular IP address, then you could delay the responses to that address, or drop them all together.

Slowing hash functions is designed to make it impractical to carry out a brute force attack if an attacker gets access to the password database. There should still be precautions built into the server as well.